# How to send of one sharepoint to other by clicking on Logo

Tags: sharepoint

I have several pages of sharepoint and i am trying to make a connection betwen them. My ideia its click on logo of share point and all go to the same "home page" , how can i do that? change the link of logo ?
Thank you in advice

Answer (score 0):

We can use the jQuery code below to modify the link of the logo, add the code into  in master page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
     $("#DeltaSiteLogo>a").attr("href","http://sp2013/sites/team");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can do this with JavaScript it's probably better to edit the masterpage and wrap an  tag around the logo.